# Spark streaming : Error running job streaming job due java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am getting below exception on **if (rdd.isEmpty()) {** check.
Basically, I am iterating over each RDD of JavaDStream and check if rdd is empty or not we save this rdd in Cassandra. We are getting NPE at the check of empty of rdd.
Look at this:

```
                if (rdd.isEmpty()) {
                    if (printTimestamp) {  
                        logger.info("No report count for this interval");
                        Predef.println("App is in INACTIVE state");
                    }
                    return;
                }
```

And here is the exception, we are getting in spark streaming job.

```
2020-06-23 03:32:01 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 0 in stage 8116.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
2020-06-23 03:32:01 ERROR JobScheduler:91 - Error running job streaming job 1592883115000 ms.6
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8116.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 8116.0 (TID 21629, 10.10.2.12, executor 0): java.lang.NullPointerException
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1353)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1326)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$isEmpty$1.apply$mcZ$sp(RDD.scala:1461)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$isEmpty$1.apply(RDD.scala:1461)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$isEmpty$1.apply(RDD.scala:1461)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.isEmpty(RDD.scala:1460)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.isEmpty(JavaRDDLike.scala:544)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.isEmpty(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at <package>.StreamingAnalytics.AnalyzeCSPReport.lambda$saveToCassandra$17d491f7$1(AnalyzeCSPReport.java:409)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$2.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$2.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:254)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:253)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```